# Chrome Extension Bind to Form Submit

Tags: google-chrome-extension, submit, bind

I'm writing a chrome extension that needs to do some work when the user submits a form.  I've got a content script running in the background that runs the following code:

```
$(document.body).on('submit', 'form', function () {
         doWork();
});
```

That works perfectly on most sites, but breaks on the login form of twitter.  Oddly, though, it doesn't break entirely.  If I **click** the 'Sign In' button on twitter, the `doWork()` function will run.  However, if I **press enter** to submit the form, `doWork()` never runs.

In my efforts to debug, I then copy and pasted my code into dev tools to rebind the function, and see if it worked.  It did - even when using enter, the new binding worked.

My next thought was that maybe jQuery.on wasn't working on elements created via javascript *(assuming the button submitted a hidden dynamically-created form via javascript, rather than the visible form, for some reason)*.  So, I rebound the event like above, but added in a line that would alert me with the class name of the submitted form - all of the forms have unique class names on the twitter login page.

As you may have unfortunately guessed, clicking 'Sign In' vs. pressing enter alerted with the same class name - so, no matter which way I look at it, I have an event bound to that form submit, but for some crazy reason it is not getting called when I press enter.